# How do I implement my special ordering as CompareTo

Tags: c#-4.0, icomparable

So I have following `struct`

```
public struct Foo
{
    public readonly int FirstLevel;
    public readonly int SecondLevel;
    public readonly int ThirdLevel;
    public readonly int FourthLevel;
}
```

Somewhere I do the following

```
var sequence = new Foo[0];
var orderedSequence = sequence
    .OrderBy(foo => foo.FirstLevel)
    .ThenBy(foo => foo.SecondLevel)
    .ThenBy(foo => foo.ThirdLevel)
    .ThenBy(foo => foo.FourthLevel);
```

Now I would like to implement `System.IComparable<Foo>` to take eg. advantage of `.Sort()` of `Foo[]`.

How do I transfer the logic (from my special/wired `OrderBy`/`ThenBy`) to `int CompareTo(Foo foo)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about something like:

```cs
public struct Foo : IComparable<Foo>
{
    public readonly int FirstLevel;
    public readonly int SecondLevel;
    public readonly int ThirdLevel;
    public readonly int FourthLevel;

    public int CompareTo(Foo other)
    {
        int result;

        if ((result = this.FirstLevel.CompareTo(other.FirstLevel)) != 0)
            return result;
        else if ((result = this.SecondLevel.CompareTo(other.SecondLevel)) != 0)
            return result;
        else if ((result = this.ThirdLevel.CompareTo(other.ThirdLevel)) != 0)
            return result;
        else 
            return this.FourthLevel.CompareTo(other.FourthLevel);
    }
}
```

Comment: (Foo other) can't be null - it's a struct, so no need to test for it.

Comment: that came to my mind either ... additionally i'm just curious if i can somehow enhance `&` or sth alike ...

Comment: @RussellTroywest, right, corrected. I had class in mind when I've been writing this.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair it stops comparing just after it finds first difference so it looks fine for me, but I can't say that there's no better way. I just don't see it ;-).